# Need help structuring a nested zgrep to produce a count

Tags: linux, grep

I've been assisting with some reporting at work, and am trying to get a unique count of different elements from some rather large log files that we are generating. So far, I've been able to run two separate commands to come up with the counts, but due to some restrictions, I'm going to have to combine them.  Here is what I have been running (the names of files, directories, search items have been changed to protect the innocent):

**Command 1** - filter by `_transformer_` and write all these unique log entries to a new file (each item that I'm counting has multiple entries per transaction, so I do this to speed up the next step as well as remove duplicates):

```
zgrep -a _transformer_ /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz > \
     /temp/directory/count_file_date.gz
```

**Command 2** - count the number of instances of each of several items related to the transactions:

```
zgrep -caE 'shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster' \
     /temp/directory/count_file_date.gz
```

This has worked great, but I want to combine them into one command and skip writing the new file. This is what I thought would work, but isn't:

**Single Command**

```
zgrep -a _transformer_ | \
zgrep -acE 'shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster' \
      /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz
```

Running the above command outputs a count of all log entries with the words between the pipes, and doesn't only count the ones with *transformer* in the particular line of the log.

Comment: You need to set the file name to be part of the first command.

Comment: I suggest with `zgrep` and GNU `grep`: `zgrep -a _transformer_ /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz | grep -acE 'shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster'`

Answer (score 0):

```
zgrep -a _transformer_ /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz |
  grep -acE 'shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster'
```

The first `zgrep` calls `gzip -dcf` on the file, then internally runs `grep -a _transformer_` on the resulting stream which produces an uncompressed stream which we pass on to another `grep` invocation, all three (gzip, grep, grep) running concurrently, there's no intermediary data ever stored on disk.

You can also run those 3 commands manually:

```
gzip -dcf /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz |
  grep -a _transformer_ |
  grep -acE 'shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster'
```

(the `-f` (when combined with `-c` and `-d`) is for `gzip` to behave like `cat` if the file happens not to be compressed, `-d` to uncompress, `-c` to output the result on stdout instead of producing an uncompressed `/files/are/located/here/logfile_date`).

It can be done in one `grep` if it supports `-P`:

```
gzip -dcf /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz |
  grep -acP '^(?=.*_transformer_).*(shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster)'
```

Or portably with `awk`:

```
gzip -dcf /files/are/located/here/logfile_date.gz |
  awk -v n=0 '
    /_transformer/ && /shockwave|starscream|megatron|prowl|blaster/ {n++}
    END {print n}'
```